# What is better and why to use List as thread safe: BlockingCollection or ReaderWriterLockSlim or lock?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, blockingcollection

I have `System.Collections.Generic.List _myList` and many threads can read from it or add items to it simultaneously. From what I've read I should using 'BlockingCollection' so this will work. I also read about `ReaderWriterLockSlim` and `lock`, but I don't figure out how to use them instead of `BlockingCollection`, so my question is can I do the same with:

1. ReaderWriterLockSlim
2. lock

instead of using 'BlockingCollection'. If YES, can you please provide simple example and what pros and cons of using `BlockingCollection`, `ReaderWriterLockSlim`, `lock`?

**UPDATED**
readers will be much more than writers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ReaderWriterLockSlim`:

- is optimized for use cases, when reads from resourse occur more frequently, than writes;
- can work with any type of resources (not only collections), because it's just a hybrid synchronization construct.

`lock`:

- is a general purpose, rather simple, hybrid synchronization construct without any optimizations; thus, can make performance worse;
- is a C# wrapper around `Monitor` class;
- can work with any type of resources;

`BlockingCollection`:

- is a specific type of collection (concrete type of resource), that oriented to solve 'producer-consumer' tasks;
- supports timeouts and cancellation mechanism (via cancellation tokens), which makes easier integration into code, which uses TPL.

I think, your choice is `BlockingCollection` (if you really have many readers and writers).

Comment: readers will be much more than writers. I updated my post accordingly

Comment: Dennis, if I'll use `BlockingCollection` I need to add some functionality for `Remove`. I can use `TryTake` but it also needs some workaround, doesn't it?

Comment: @theateist: what kind of workaround do you mean? `BlockingCollection` hasn't `Remove` method because there can be nothing to remove at the moment. It's normal for the multi-threading environment.

Comment: So, how do I remove item from the collection?

Comment: But what if `Take` or `TryTake` fails? I need to have another queue that will hold all items that couldn't be taken and retry after that again(maybe by another thread?), do I?

Comment: No, you don't. If `Take` or `TryTake` fails, this means that collection is empty and all items are already processed.

Comment: I understood. If I would have threads that won't just take item from that BlockingCollection, but they should take specific item and remove it, I think `BlockingCollection` is not good for this, am I right? If I do, what would you suggest to use?

Comment: @theateist: in general, yes, you're right. You can't **peek** some `BlockingCollection`'s item, analyze it contents and skip it, if it is not satisfying any condition - you must **take** it (remove from collection). It's hard to recommend any concrete solution - I don't know your task's specific. I think, more abstract recommendations will be off topic, and I recommend to ask new, more concrete question.

Answer (score 3):

If you are *mutating* the list frequently, then `ReaderWriterLockSlim` probably isn't going to help you, as that only allows single write access, and `lock` is less overhead. Personally, I would just `lock` (on some lock object) for the duration of each access.

The problem with a `BlockingCollection` is that it only guarantees that individual operations are atomic - however, quite often we need to perform *multiple* operations as a unit (more than just `TryAdd`, etc). So in order to avoid crazy, a `lock` is simpler.

The other advantage is that the usage of `lock` is very simple:

```
lock(syncLock) {
   // do stuff with the list
}
```

(it also has inbuilt signalling via `Monitor.Wait` and `Monitor.Pulse*`, which is nice)

Comment: I agree with this. No need for the hassle of `BlockingCollection` for a simple use case.